# How to provide the output result of a function as a PUT request in scala?

Tags: scala, rest, put

i have a scala code that converts a layer to a Geotiff file. Now i want this Geotiff file to be passed in a PUT request as a REST service. How can i do that?

Here is a section of code:

```
val labeled_layerstack =
    {
      //Labeled Layerstack
      //val layers_input = Array(layer_dop) ++ layers_sat
      val layers_labeled_input = Array(layer_label) ++ Array(output_layerstack) //++ layers_input
      ManyLayersToMultibandLayer(layers_labeled_input, output_labeled_layerstack)
      output_labeled_layerstack
    }

    if (useCleanup) {
      DeleteLayer(layer_label)
      if(useDOP)
        DeleteLayer(layer_dop)
      for( layer_x <- layers_sat)
        DeleteLayer(layer_x)
    }
    labeled_layerstack
  }
  else output_labeled_layerstack  //if reusing existing layerstack ( processing steps w/o "layerstack")

  if(processingSteps.isEmpty || processingSteps.get.steps.exists(step => step == "classification")) {
    if (useRandomForest) {
      ClusterTestRandomForest(labeled_layerstack, fileNameClassifier, layerResult, Some(output_layerstack))
      if (useExportResult) {
        LayerToGeotiff(layerResult, fileNameResult, useStitching = useExportStitching)
      }
    }
    else if (useSVM) {
      ClusterTestSVM(labeled_layerstack, fileNameClassifier, layerResult, Some(output_layerstack))
      if (useExportResult) {
        LayerToGeotiff(layerResult, fileNameResult, useStitching = useExportStitching)
      }
    }
  }
```

The original code is quite long and is not shareable so i am sharing this which is relevant to the problem. The output of `LayertoGeotiff` should be passed as an PUT request. How can i create such a request?

Comment: Which lib ils used? (P.s. the code structure is far from being Scala idiomatic)

Comment: You need to chose some library to do the request. There are many of them, even the standard **Java** library provides the basis to that. You can Google for this libraries and examples, or you can ask in **gitter** or in **Reddit** for suggestions.

Comment: Unrelated, but [naming conventions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) are important. `ThisIsAClassName`, `thisIsAMethodOrValue`, `this_is_some_other_language_not_scala`

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to you the Play framework to send a PUT request